# How does one bind namespace prefixes when using QXmlQuery (Qt XQuery)?

Tags: c++, qt, xquery

I'm attempting to use QXmlQuery to execute an XQuery expression against a document with a declared default namespace.

For discussion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://namespace.com/ns1">
    <node1 attr1="hi"/>
</root>
```

Now, I have the following to open and query against the document:

```
QFile temp("my.xml");
temp.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);

QXmlQuery query;
query.setFocus(&temp);

QXmlResultItems items;
query.setQuery("/root");

query.evaluateTo(&items);
```

In running this, 'items' never has data in it, since the document is namespaced. Of course, if I remove the default namespace declaration, 'items' does have the correct data, but I don't have that luxury.

I've tried changing the query to: "/prefix:root", and Qt barks a warning like:

```
No namespace binding exists for the prefix prefix in prefix:root
```

So namespace binding does exist!  But where?  I see QXmlNamePool, but it has no mutator methods.  I can create a QXmlName with the pool from the query ala:

```
QXmlName name(query.namePool(), "prefix", "http://namespace.com/ns1");
```

But it doesn't change anything.  I'm at a loss, other toolkits I have used have simple methods to bind prefixes to namespace URIs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe if you would change your query to

```
...
QXmlResultItems items;
query.setQuery("declare default element namespace \"http://namespace.com/ns1\"; /root");
...
```

it should return the data.

hope this helps, regards

Comment: That works!  That's absolutely horrible API on Qt's part, but it works.  Thanks!

Comment: @Nick Veys: This is an [XQuery](http://www.w3.org/XML/Query/) expression, not XPath.

Comment: @Alejandro: Is there a better class to be using then?  It claims XPath support, as it's a subset of XQuery.

Comment: @Nick Veys: I would use XQuery/XPath 2.0 over any XPath 1.0 engine

Comment: I can't disagree, however requirements tend to trump preference.  Thanks for the help!