# namespace declaring clause causing compiling error (Qt XQuery)

Tags: c++, xml, qt, xpath, xquery

I'm using the `QXmlQuery` class in Qt to do XQuery on a soap response. As the response contains two namespaces, I use the declare clauses (the second and the third lines in the code snippet below) to declare them first before using them in the Xpath expression.

> QXmlQuery query;
>
> declare namespace s = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope";
>
> declare namespace ms =
>   "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/";
>
> query.setQuery("doc($xmlDoc)/s:Envelope/s:Body/ms:GetListCollectionResponse/ms:GetListCollectionResult/ms:Lists/ms:List/string()");

However, I got the following errors when compiling the code. Does anybody know how to fix this?

```
src/QtHelloWorldMakeCommImpl.cpp:79: error: 'declare' was not declared in this scope
src/QtHelloWorldMakeCommImpl.cpp:79: error: expected ';' before 'namespace'
src/QtHelloWorldMakeCommImpl.cpp:80: error: expected ';' before 'namespace'
```

Comment: Not sure about `QXmlQuery`, but it looks like you would try to declare the namespaces outside the query. There must be some function like query.declareNamespace or similar.

Answer (score 1):

The "declare" statement is an XQuery statement, but you use it directly in the C++ file - this can't work. I have no Qt install here, but the following *should* work

```
QString queryStr(
"declare namespace s = \"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\";\n"
"declare namespace ms = \"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\";\n"
"doc($xmlDoc)/s:Envelope/s:Body/ms:GetListCollectionResponse/ms:GetListCollectionResult/ms:Lists/ms:List/string()");

query.setQuery(queryStr);
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [this answer on how to declare namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011557/how-does-one-bind-namespace-prefixes-when-using-qxmlquery-qt-xquery). You try to declare it in C++-Code where `declare` is no keyword neighter you declarated it.

This should work:

```
query.setQuery("declare namespace s = \"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\"; declare namespace ms = \"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\"; doc($xmlDoc)/s:Envelope/s:Body/ms:GetListCollectionResponse/ms:GetListCollectionResult/ms:Lists/ms:List/string()");
```

Comment: I suspect Ranon had the right idea but suffered finger-trouble supplying the code.

Comment: Guess you're totally right. Must have missed the preview. Copy-pasting seems to be quiet difficult.

Comment: Thanks, Ranon and Mike! By doing what Ranon suggested, the compiling error went away. query.isValid() returns true. However, query.evaluateTo(&segments) return false (segments is a QStringList instance to hold the query result) and hence I get an empty query result. I double check my query and they should be correct. Any further suggestion on how to debug further. I tried using F5 to step into the evaluateTo() function but didn't succeed. Thanks again!

Comment: Please provide some well-formed XML snippet against which we can run the query. Add small fragments to your question, bigger could be posted on [gist](http://gist.github.com) for example.

Comment: I posted my source code and the xml document to the following link. Would be appreciated if you can take a look. Thanks a lot! https://gist.github.com/1355120

Comment: The XML file you provided is empty.